# При meta charset=utf-8 не выводит строку

Tags: php, utf-8, кодировка

Всем привет. Беру все файлы из папки через `scandir()`, получаю строку в UTF-8. Т.е. `mb_detect_encoding()` выводит UTF-8, но на странице выводит как знаки вопроса. Если убираю из `<head>` `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`, то названия папок считываются, но весь остальной текст сходит на нет. Пробовал уже делать `utf8_encode()`, ничего не вышло (да и идея сама по себе глупая -из utf8 делать utf8). Что делать?

Файл, который сканирует папку, сохранен в utf-8 without bom.

Скрин документа с `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без `meta`: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин дампа массива и результата mb_detect_encoding(): 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Лев Калинин` у вас точно хранится не в кодировке utf-8. Там однобайтовая кодировка, по первому скрину видно.

Comment: @Visman тогда почему на `mb_detect_encoding()` он выводит UTF-8 и что с этим делать?

Comment: Файлы все в кодировку UTF-8 перекодируйте и используйте дальше без всяких mb_detect_encoding(), mb_convert_encoding().

Comment: @Visman все файлы в UTF-8 идут. Еще один скрин приложил с дампом массива

Comment: Третий скрин показывает проверку кодировки имени файла, а не его содержимого :) Еще раз говорю: из первого скрина следует однобайтовая кодировка, а ни как не UTF-8.

Comment: @Visman мне и нужно получить название файла в нормальном виде))

Comment: попробуй так:
`$str = inconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'utf-8', $str);`
и посмотри что там с заголовками, с метой и без... может поймёшь...

Answer (score -1):

Судя по всему, данные, полученные из БД обрабатываются в однобайтовой кодировке. Соответственно, при выводе на страницу пачка однобайтнокодированных символов оказывается среди utf-8. Очевидно, что в таком случае одна из двух частей страницы будет показана неверно, что и наблюдается на скриншотах.

Следует хранить данные в БД в юникоде и обеспечить их вывод на страницу в utf-8.

Comment: Вопрос-то прочитайте внимательно прежде чем отвечать. Речь совсем не о БД идет.